# Trying to use MSBuild and a csproj file to compile C files

Tags: c, msbuild

project.csproj

```
    <Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
            <ItemGroup>
                    <Compile Include="main.c" />
            </ItemGroup>
            <Target Name="Build">
                    <Csc Sources="@(Compile)"/>
            </Target>
    
    </Project>
```

main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>


    int main(int argc, char* argv) {
    
            printf("Hello World");
    
    
            return 0;
    
    }
```

```
MSBuild.exe project.csproj -t:Build
```

I get an error that says "preprocessor directive expected".

Build FAILED.

"C:\Users\micha\Projects\3dworld-windows-C\src\project.csproj" (default target) (1) ->
(Build target) ->
main.c(1,2): error CS1024: Preprocessor directive expected [C:\Users\micha\Projects\3dworld-windows-C\src\project.csproj]

```
0 Warning(s)
1 Error(s)
```

Can MSBuild compile .c files?  How would I go about compiling C with MSBuild.  When I compile main.c with gcc there is no problem.

Comment: So after further searching I discovered cl.exe for c programs but it can't find stdio.h.  Visual Studio doesnt seem to have a copy of that file.  What is the best way to get access to stdio.h?  Should I download the headers?

Answer (score 1):

I was using cygwin and it does not have includes set.  So I am using the developer tools for windows now and everything works with that.